# Where would the reproductive organs be on an insect-millipede?

Tags: biology, creature-design, mythical-creatures

I had an idea for a creature that is a hybrid of an insect and a millipede. More specifically, it has the body of a millipede with the head and thorax of an insect, replacing the millipede head and thorax. However, there is a small problem with this setup: Millipedes have their reproductive organs on their thorax, and insects have them in their abdomen. This means that the hybrid, as I have described it, would have no reproductive organs. Where would be the best place to add in the reproductive organs?

Comment: Wherever you like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some millipedes ([Pentazonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentazonia)) have their reproductive parts at the rear. Even among other millipedes, assexual reproduction via parthenogenesis is common, to the point of them having near no males.

But this reall boils down to "if my species would wear pants, how would they do it?" And it's all up to you - you are already in pretty alien territory anyway.

Wanna make it shocking and interesting? Put the genitals inside the mouth. Evolution might favor it because it simplifies mating so much; And with insects at least sperm can enter the body from wherever, even wounds. As long as it's in the female's body, her eggs will be fertilized.

Comment: See the [Phallostethus Cuulong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phallostethus_cuulong) for an Earth bound example of _misplaced_ genitals.

Comment: @AlexisWilke wow, thanks! Once again we think we are orogonal, but nature's already done it!

Answer (score 2):

**Depends on how you make them**

Reproductive organs for creatures that need to copulate only require two things. Space on/inside the body and accessibility to the other's reproductive organs. Whether at the thorax or the abdomen, they just need to be able to reach and exist. There is a stipulation that the reproductive organs require more space at times for many creatures, just as an extra reminder.

As we don't know the exact body plan (drawings, organ placements, etc.) we can't tell you where to place it. However, using the rules above it should be easy to determine. Just imagine how they would easiest copulate and how the rest of the organs can still work.